# Windows: List shared folder paths in my computer with associated share names

Tags: windows, network-shares, shared-folders

How do I get a list of network shares on my computer with the associated path names for each shared folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from a command prompt or powershell, simply run

```
net share
```

and a list of all shares with Name, Local path (resource), and administrative remarks about the share

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> net share

Share name   Resource                        Remark

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
C$           C:\                             Default share
D$           D:\                             Default share
F$           F:\                             Default share
G$           G:\                             Default share
IPC$                                         Remote IPC
ADMIN$       C:\Windows                      Remote Admin
isos         D:\isos
Source       D:\Source
The command completed successfully.

PS C:\Windows\system32>
```

Answer (score 2):

For client operating systems starting from Windows Vista, and server operating system starting from Windows Server 2003, you can use [`wmic`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394531(v=vs.85).aspx).

```
wmic share get caption,name,path
```

Comment: Windows 2000 and later: `net share`